# Execute Unittest in Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-unittest

I have written a small unit test for my django view .My project structure is like

Project_name/

```
         apps/

              module1/
                      tests.py
              module2/
                      tests.py
```

this is my dir structure i am executing the tests by using the command :

$python manage.py test_coverage module1 module2 -v2

then it executing the test nicely  but now i have change dir structure little bit i have created a new directory tests/ in that i have kept my all test files

project_name/

```
       apps/

            module1/
                    tests/
                         test_basic.py
                         test_detail.py
```

Now i can able to execute those tests which are in dir with the same above command ,is their is any alternative way to execute such tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to add `__init__.py` file to `tests/` package containing following lines:

```
from .test_basic import *
from .test_detail import *
```

And then run all the tests with:

```
$ python manage.py test module1
```

Comment: Hye Łukasz its works...very thanks.But can u plz explain me why and when we need to use dot(.) while importing files.

Comment: @Shashi [See here for Python relative imports](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#id10).